# BLE Paired device list

Tags: android

I am developing an application which scans for Bluetooth Low Energy devices.The scanned devices are stored in a database.My problem is I want to display a list of devices from this database and on click of this device list item I want to know the device name and mac id.So anyone help me on this.

```
public class main_activity extends Activity {
public ImageButton fabbutton;
Activity activity;
DisplayMetrics metrics;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private ArrayList<String> liste;
private ListView list;
private AlertDialog.Builder builder;
public EditText input;
String name,address,Devicename,Deviceaddress;
public String SelectedDeviceName;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
private Handler mHandler;
private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;

private static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 10000;    // Stops scanning after 10 seconds.
SqlHandler sh = new SqlHandler(this);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity);
    fabbutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.fabbutton);


    final ActionBar mActionBar = getActionBar();
    mActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    mActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    mActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0xffffffff));
    activity = this;
    metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    mHandler = new Handler();

    //mActionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.back);

    mActionBar.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#727272'>Board List</font>"));
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    liste = new ArrayList<String>();
    liste.clear();
    sh.openDB();
    Cursor cur = sh.getAllnames();
    while(cur.moveToNext()){
         name = cur.getString(0);
         address = cur.getString(1);
         liste.add(name);
    }



    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(list.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, liste);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    sh.close();


   // scanDeviceList.setAdapter(mLeDeviceListAdapter);




    final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();


    fabbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ScanList.class);
            startActivity(intent);


        }

    });

    // On Long Click Listener for Paired BLE Device List
    list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            SelectedDeviceName = list.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();


            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),SelectedDeviceName,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            showRenameOrDeleteDialog();
            return true;

        }
    });



    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || !mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);
    }

}


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // System.out.println("resultCode" + resultCode);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

    }
    if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth is Required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();

    }

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main_activity, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {

        return true;
    }
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        finish();
    }


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void showRenameOrDeleteDialog() {


    //set alert builder to delete or rename the device item
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(main_activity.this);
    builder.setTitle("CREVAVI");
    builder.setMessage("Tap on Rename to rename the device, Tap on Delete to remove the device");



    builder.setPositiveButton("Rename", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Add your code for the button here.
            dialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(main_activity.this, "Rename the device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            showRenameDialog();
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Add your code for the button here.
            dialog.dismiss();
            sh.openDB();
            sh.deleteItem(SelectedDeviceName);
            sh.close();
            notifyDataChange();



        }
    });

    builder.show();
}

private void showRenameDialog() {
   final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(main_activity.this);
    alert.setTitle("Rename the device"); //Set Alert dialog title here
    alert.setMessage("Enter new Name Here"); //Message here


    // Set an EditText view to get user input
    input = new EditText(main_activity.this);
    alert.setView(input);


    alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(input.getWindowToken(), 0);
            //You will get as string input data in this variable.
            // here we convert the input to a string and show in a toast.
            String srt = input.getEditableText().toString();
            sh.openDB();
            sh.updateData("Hello", srt, SelectedDeviceName);
            sh.close();







           // adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            dialog.dismiss();

        } // End of onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)

    }); //End of alert.setPositiveButton
    alert.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(input.getWindowToken(), 0);
            // Canceled.
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    }); //End of alert.setNegativeButton
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}

public void notifyDataChange(){
    liste.clear();
    sh.openDB();
    Cursor cur = sh.getAllnames();
    while(cur.moveToNext()){
        String name = cur.getString(0);
        liste.add(name);
    }
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(list.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, liste);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    sh.close();
}}
```

Comment: And what you've done so far?

Comment: I have done the scanning activity and storing the scanned device in database.

Comment: i am storing the device name and mac id in database along with some other details not related to device. i want a list which displays device name  from database and on click i want the device name and address. remember i am storing upto eigth devices in database and al device name are the same. so cannot send a query based on name.

Comment: can anyone please help me on this.